# Trying to create constant class changing

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I just startet exploring Jquery, actually I am trying to realize one of my first designs.

THE PROBLEM is, that I want (in this simple example) three div boxes to change their classes individualy different by clicking on one of the divs and this seems to be possible for only one time!

At the same time I want it to be dynamic, so i used ".switchClass"(after ".toggleClass" and ".removeClass().addClass() ) and jquery UI to have a visible transformation.

It would be great and satisfying if s.o. could explain to me, how I can switch the classes more than one time.

Please excuse my underground-coding... I am a newby.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="testgetid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<title>keepitclear</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="green" class="Aindex">A</div>
    <div id="red" class="Bindex">B</div>
    <div id="blue" class="Cindex">C</div>

</div>

<script>
      $('#green').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('Aaaaaa');
      $('#red').toggleClass('Baaaaa');
      $('#blue').toggleClass('Caaaaa');
  });
      $('#red').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('Bbbbbb');
      $('#green').toggleClass('Abbbbb');
      $('#blue').toggleClass('Cbbbbb');
  });

      $('#blue').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('Cccccc');
      $('#green').toggleClass('Accccc');
      $('#red').toggleClass('Bccccc');
  });


 </script>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS(required, because nice):

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}

#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

.Aindex{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  100px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #53D35F;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Aaaaaa{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  0px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #99F748;
}

.Abbbbb{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  125px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #287F28;
}

.Accccc{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  125px;
    margin-left: 275px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #287F28;
}


.Bindex{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  200px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F48725;
}   

.Baaaaa{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  175px;
    margin-left: 225px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #9E2B15;
}


.Bbbbbb{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  150px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #F4dC76;
}
.Bccccc{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  150px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #9E2B15;
}

.Cindex{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  200px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #1FA2FF;
}   




.Caaaaa{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  175px;
    margin-left: 425px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4F35D3;
}


.Cbbbbb{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  175px;
    margin-left: 375px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4F35D3;
}

.Cccccc{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:  150px;
    margin-left: 275px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #1FFFFA;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.. Can you explain what exactly is supposed to happen or isn't happening?  It seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/AThVQ/

Comment: @wirey he just want to know if there is another dynamic way to use toggleClass and not calling it lots of times.

Comment: A user you must have the possibility to click on each box, no matter which one is selected. The animation has to stay...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but I guess all you need to do is keep track of the state of the boxes using a variable, so for example, if you wanted to have 2 different toggle types for each button:

```
var green_state=1, red_state=1, blue_state=1;

    $('#green').click(function () {
        //maybe you want to reset blue and red state here
        switch(green_state){
            case 1:
                green_state=2;
                //toggle code for first state
                break;
            case 2:
                green_state=1;
                //toggle code for second state
                break;
        }
    }
```

Obviously you would repeat this for each button... This is one approach but if you can explain what you are trying to do a bit better you may get a better answer.

Comment: hey webweaver, thanks for trying to find an answer. what i am trying is pretty simple in the end! 
I just want the user to have the possibility to select one of the other divs, while having another one "selected". F.E. #green works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

### **Improved version:**

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/pmbjk/2/

Look that the `toogleClass` is used outside and you are not using `click();` event **3** times *(that's a kind of improvement)*.

That's all I can do *(I think)* because each element needs to be replaced with another particular `class` and I can't group all them or do something else like a *"global"* or *"constant"* `toogleClass` because they don't share any `class` between them.

---

***HTML:***

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-color="green" class="Aindex">A</div>
    <div data-color="red" class="Bindex">B</div>
    <div data-color="blue" class="Cindex">C</div>
</div>
```

***jQuery:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* get all squares inside 'wrapper' div */
    var squares = $('#wrapper').find('div');

    squares.click(function(e) {
        /* detect which element was clicked */
        var square = $(e.target);
        /* get the color of the square element */
        var color = square.data('color');
        /* pass parameters to the method that will toogle class */
        toogleClassElems(color, square);
    });

});

function toogleClassElems(color, square) {
    if (color === 'green') {
        square.toggleClass('Aaaaaa'); //actual square
        square.next().toggleClass('Baaaaa'); //red square
        square.next().next().toggleClass('Caaaaa'); //blue square
    } else if (color === 'red') {
        square.toggleClass('Bbbbbb'); //actual square
        square.prev().toggleClass('Abbbbb'); //green square
        square.next().toggleClass('Cbbbbb'); //blue square 
    } else if (color === 'blue') {
        square.toggleClass('Cccccc'); //actual square
        square.prev().prev().toggleClass('Accccc'); //green square
        square.prev().toggleClass('Bccccc'); //red square
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest answer, but if you want to use switchClass instead - you can check to see what class it has currently and switch depending on that

```
var $red = $('#red');
var $blue = $('#blue');
var $green = $('#green');
$('#green').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);        
    if ($this.hasClass('Aaaaaa')) {
        $this.switchClass('Aaaaaa', '', 1000);
        $red.switchClass('Baaaaa', '', 1000);
        $blue.switchClass('Caaaaa', '', 1000);
    } else {
        $this.switchClass('', 'Aaaaaa', 1000);
        $red.switchClass('', 'Baaaaa', 1000);
        $blue.switchClass('', 'Caaaaa', 1000);
    }
});
$red.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('Bbbbbb')) {
       $this.switchClass('Bbbbbb', '', 1000);
       $green.switchClass('Abbbbb', '', 1000);
       $blue.switchClass('Cbbbbb', '', 1000);
    }else{
       $this.switchClass('', 'Bbbbbb', 1000);
       $green.switchClass('','Abbbbb',1000);
       $blue.switchClass('','Cbbbbb',1000);
    }    
});

$('#blue').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('Cccccc')) {
        $this.switchClass('Cccccc', '', 1000);
        $green.switchClass('Accccc', '', 1000);
        $red.switchClass('Bccccc', '', 1000);
    }else{
        $this.switchClass('', 'Cccccc', 1000);
        $green.switchClass('','Accccc',1000);
        $red.switchClass('','Bccccc',1000);
    }   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fT3we/